# Are there algorithms to (approximately?) sort data that can change?

Tags: data-structures

All sorting algorithms I know require exclusive access to the data structure they work on. Are there any that can handle data that can change at any time?

To make this possible at all, we can certainly assume:

1. The rate of change is low, let's say i.e. we will repeatedly have enough time to walk through the whole structure and verify that it is currently sorted.
2. All changes are atomic and do not violate integrity, i.e. we won't deal with accidentally lost pointers etc., and all changes can be assumed to perform additional actions to ensure the structure is still connected (let's say in at most O(log n) time).

I'm interested in any information, papers or implementations, also if they have more or less strict assumptions than those above.

Comment: [I don't know about publications] Things like this occur if the ordering is relaticvely stable and relatively unimportant. Example: the candidate moves for a given position in a chess-engine, orderered by their cost or gain. Or: weighted sampling using a stochastic vector in a simulation. Often, a 1-pass bubblesort, or an insertion/selection kind of scheme is used.

Answer (score 0):

Many, many data structures maintain data in sorted order. For example, any tree, skiplist, heap, etc., allows ordered access. In general, inserting, removing or updating a data item is O(log N) or better (N = number of items in the dataset). Therefore you can expect the cost of maintaining the sorted invariant for the dataset over a time interval to be O(M*log(N)), where M is the number of items you insert/delete/update in that time interval.

Some sorting algorithms (insertion sort for example) perform better when data is partially sorted. At best, the cost of running such an algorithm is O(N), but this happens only in very limited circumstances. On average you can expect it to be closer to O(N*log(N)).

Therefore, if the sorting invariant of the dataset needs to be maintained at all times you should use a data structure like an index or heap. However, if you only need to have the data sometimes, it might be more efficient to just buffer the updates in an array and re-sort the whole dataset whenever needed.

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood the question - I'm specifically looking for data structures that can handle "volatile" content, i.e. content that changes while the structure performs its operations (the usual (exclusive-access) structures and algorithms cannot do that). The bounds of the more complex process are of minor relevance, anything within, say, O(n^3) would be fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

Most comparison/exchange sorts should be able to mostly sort an array that is being modified. Insertion sort and Shell sort certainly can, as can Bubble sort and even selection sort. I'm not entirely sure about Quicksort. Seems like some implementations could go into an infinite loop if a data value got changed in the middle of the sort.

Consider the simple case of insertion sort. Start with the array `[4, 7, 5, 3, 2]`.

After a few iterations you have: `[3, 4, 5, 7, 2]`. At this point somebody reaches in and changes that `4` to a `1`, giving you `[3, 1, 5, 7, 2]`. Your sort is trying to place the last item, `2`. It'll end up giving you `[3, 1, 2, 7, 5]`, and since it's placed the last element that's what your final array will look like.

In an array that changes infrequently, you'll likely have just a few items out of place and Insertion sort could quickly put things in order.

You have to be careful with your implementation, though. Because other threads could be modifying the array, you can't have a temporary variable holding the contents of an array item. If the items in the array are references that won't change (i.e. only the thing being referred to can change, not the element in the array itself), then holding that reference in a temporary is no problem. But if the array is, say, an array of integers, then all comparisons have to be done against the actual array elements rather than by holding a value in a temporary.

That said, such a thing is fairly unusual. Many ordered data structures can be coded to be lock-free such that multiple threads can be reading and/or writing concurrently. That removes the need to "approximately" sort anything, as the data structure maintains order at all times.